# kubernetes didn't create heapdump when pod is restarted

Tags: kubernetes, restart, heap-dump

I have a problem.
There is preStop option in manifest file and OOMKilled was happened.
pod was restarted but no heapdump is created.

lifecycle:
preStop:
exec:
command: ["/tmp/preStop.sh"]

heapdump works when I manually terminate the pod.

so I wonder if pod is restarted, preStop is not supposed to be executed?

I thought when pod is restarted, first send TermSignal to application and execute preStop and terminate and start pod again. Am I wrong?

Thanks
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior for OOMKilled pods to not invoke preStop hook.

As explained by Chanpreet08 (GitHub user)

> K8 gives SIGTERM signal if it wants to terminate the pod, but in case
> of OOM, it passes SIGKILL to the pod which instantly kills the main
> process and finally terminates the pod without waiting for the prestop
> to execute. So in case of OOM, the prestop won;t execute.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/93818

Comment: Wow thank you very much! This is what exactly Im looking for. _()_

Answer (score 2):

> when the pod is restarted, first send TermSignal to the application
> and execute preStop and terminate and start pod again. Am I wrong?

As per the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks)

> `PreStop` hooks are not executed asynchronously from the signal to
> stop the Container; the hook must complete its execution before the
> **TERM** signal can be sent.
>
> If a `PreStop` hook hangs during execution, the Pod's phase will be
> **Terminating** and remain there until the Pod is killed after its `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` expires. This grace period applies to
> the total time it takes for both the PreStop hook to execute and for
> the Container to stop normally.

Hope the above information is useful to you.

Comment: @user2286858 is your issue resolved? let me know if you need any additional help.